# How to freeze the screen when taking a screenshot with scrot, while not being in select mode?

Tags: screenshot

I'm having an issue:
I want to be able to take a screenshot with scrot and I want the screen to freeze when doing so, this would normally be achieved with "scrot -f", this only works when in the select mode, so "scrot -s -f", I do not want to take a screenshot of a selection though, does anyone know how to get this to work?
Thanks in advance.